# fatal: Could not parse object '4eb38c748f77b51ffcde8684dfea173af2e33e7b'

Tags: git, git-commit

I am trying this

```
git reset --hard 4eb38c748f77b51ffcde8684dfea173af2e33e7b
```

I am getting an error

```
fatal: Could not parse object '4eb38c748f77b51ffcde8684dfea173af2e33e7b'.
```

Why would I get this error? How can I fix my command?

Comment: This answer could help U https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Comment: This message indicates git could not find this commit in its store. Can you indicate how you found this hash ?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have *all* the latest commits:

```
git fetch
```

Second, try and git rev-parse the first 7 or 8 characters of your SHA1

```
git rev-parse 4eb38c7
```

If there is a unique existing commit SHA1 starting with `4eb38c7`, that command will display it completely.
You can then compare with the full SHA1 string you were trying to use: maybe there was a typo in it.